# WordPress External Link Disclaimer Page

Tags: wordpress

I am currently using this script to warn the user they are leaving the current webiste when clicking on an external link on a WordPress website:

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
function leave_now(event) {
var choice = window.confirm( 'Leave page?' );
return choice;
}

var select_external = 'a[href*="//"]:not([href*="yourdomain.com"])';
jQuery(document).on( 'click', select_external, leave_now )
});
</script>
```

It works great, but I actually need to modify this so it takes them to a warning PAGE instead of having a popup window appear.  After the warning page is loaded, it waits 5 seconds, then loads the URL that was clicked on.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `location.href` which will navigate you to the url you specify
`location.href='http://www.your-url.com'`

So, on click, you could have that function run and set that location instead of do a warning